# CSS - Could this be created with CSS rather than <table>?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website based on a designers photoshop mock-ups.

[image: Mock-up]

Here is a part of a question form. I know this could be created with a HTML table fairly easily, but as tables are supposed to be used for data, I would rather use CSS.

I am trying to work out if this could be created with 3 separate columns, one for the radio buttons, another for the titles, and the other for the text boxes, but I am unsure how to get the features to line up ("Account" radio box to line up with "Name" and its text box).

Should this be done with CSS or table?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot as to how you want it to look? I realise it's 3 columns, but still... Help us help you.

Comment: @seemly oops took one, but forgot to attach. I have added the link to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

- `display:table;` for `<table>`
- `display:table-row;` for `<tr>`
- `display:table-cell;` for `<td>`
  in div format

[**here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/27SBX/4/) (*it has css table **vs** html table-compare for your understanding*)

**CSS** to play with

```
body{
     height:100%;
}
#main{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}
.table{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
.tr{
    display:table-row;
}
.td{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your image, you will need a layout something like this  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/27SBX/2/)

**CSS**

```
body {
    height:100%;
}
#main {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
.tr {
    display:table-row;
}
.td {
    display:table-cell;
}
.td > span {
    display:list-item;
    list-style:none;
}
.td3 >span {
    background:grey;
    height:16px;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td td1"> <span>Project </span>  <span>Account</span>  <span>General bsns</span> 
            </div>
            <!-- //td -->
            <div class="td td2"> <span>Ref</span>  <span>Tite</span>  <span>Name</span> 
            </div>
            <!-- //td -->
            <div class="td td3"> <span>Insert Project Ref</span>  <span>Insert Project Title</span>  <span>Insert Account Nama</span> 
            </div>
            <!-- //td -->
        </div>
        <!-- //tr -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again NoobEditor. I think you may have helped me with something similar before. I just couldn't get my head around it this time, but I will be sure to learn it! Thanks!

Comment: Should be fine. I will have a play and shouldn't be hard to make it look like this: http://imgur.com/mfyxXe9

Comment: definitely, just set parent `divs` and `html` `height:100%`...and you'll have these design with ease!! :)