# Left and right DIVs not adjusting automatically to height on container

Tags: css

I have a grid of 9 div tags. So there's 3 rows of 3 divs.

Each div has a background image (except the second div in the second row) and I need the divs either side on the left and right to automatically adjust depending on the height of the middle div.

How can I do this?

Here's the jsfiddle to illustrate my point: http://jsfiddle.net/TZCj2/2/ - As you can see, the two divs on either side to not automatically adjust.

Many thanks.

```
<head>
<style>
#top-left {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
}
#top-right {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
}
#top {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/25x25);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 25px;
}
#bottom-left {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
}
#bottom-right {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
}
#bottom {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/25x25);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 25px;
}
#left {
    width: 25px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/25x25);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#right {
    width: 25px;
    float: right;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/25x25);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#middle {
    padding: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="top-left"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" width="25" height="25"></div>
<div id="top-right"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" width="25" height="25"></div>
<div id="top"></div>

<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="middle">
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
</div>
<div id="bottom-left"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25g" width="25" height="25"></div>
<div id="bottom-right"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" width="25" height="25"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: didn't get your question...you want `left`, `right` and `middle` id's to align properly according to window???

Comment: I want to be able to add content to the middle div. I then want the left and right div to adjust in height accordingly the the height of the middle div.

Comment: you have `height:25px` set to those `id`s already...they are going to get aligned anyway ( *scrollar may appear from overflow content* ) as far as height is concerned....i dont see a question really!!!

Comment: On 'left' and 'right' there is no height of 25px. There is 100% height instead.

Comment: In short, I need 3 divs side by side. I also need the divs on the left and the right automatically adjust their height to match the height of the middle div.

Comment: use css tables...`display:table`....is that an option???

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this page which fixed my issue: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: this one is far better and easy -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801829/css-could-this-be-created-with-css-rather-than-table/20801847#20801847